# re-render the component when retrieving data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When i fetch data from firebase the request still running and the data is still running in the console i don't know why it didn't stop
i used cleanup function, abort controller but it didn't work
here is my code

i hope you can help me

```
const [fetchedPhoto, setFetchedPhoto]= useState({
    imagUrl:[]
})

const retrieveImg= useCallback(async() => { 
    try{
        const url=[]
        const data= await fetch('https://naif-65aa6.firebaseio.com/test-project.json',{signal:controller.signal})
        const response= await data.json()
        
        for(const key in response){
            url.push({
                id: key,
                name: response[key].name,
                phone: response[key].phone
            })
        }

        setFetchedPhoto(prevState=>({
            ...prevState,
            imagUrl: prevState.imagUrl.concat(url)
        }))

        console.log(fetchedPhoto.imagUrl);

     } catch(err) {
         console.log(err);
     }
},[fetchedPhoto])

useEffect(()=>{
    retrieveImg()
           
    return()=>controller.abort()
},[fetchedPhoto])
```

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: the setState still adding the fetched data again and again, if the fetched data is an object contains 3 indexes it will duplicate it as infinite loop

Comment: Yeah the way you pass dep-list basically ensures you get an infinite loop. So tell us what is the desired behavior?

Comment: i just want to retrieve data once and when push new data the function retrieve it, like firebase realTimeDatabase when i add something it will retrieve it, i hope you understand me

Comment: Then just pass in an empty array as dep-list.

Comment: above in my code, the component should update when fetchPhoto state update, but still re-render the component every time, not only once or when pushing new data

Comment: if i pass an empty array it will update the component ever until i refresh the page, i want to retrieve it when push new data to database

Comment: Then what mechanism do you use to notify react to refresh?

Comment: useEffect but dependency when fetchPhoto changes, am i right ?

Comment: I’m so confused. You’re depending on change of `fetchedPhoto` to call `retrieveImg`, but inside `retrieveImg` you update `fetchedPhoto`, obviously this will cause infinite loop.

Comment: Maybe get rid of your code and describe your situation in plain english. I don’t even understand what problem are you facing now.

Comment: hackape, can i get any social contact to explain to you what i mean, twitter, instagram i'm in this problem for maybe 2 weeks

Comment: http://www.disposablechat.com/chat/aziz?password=

Comment: i'm in the chat hackape

Comment: To be honest, I’m not sure how social contact help to clarify. You should try harder to better describe your problem. Stack Overflow don’t limit your text length, so go lengthy if you have to, you can post image too.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events I guess this doc should help you.